# How do I choose or change the app to open an Airdrop file such as cbz, or just have it untouched in the Download folder?

Tags: ios, ipad, airdrop, ipados

I tried to Airdrop a file from the MacBook to my iPad Pro, and it succeeded, except the file is directly opened by QQ Reader which I downloaded long time ago, and the file is missing in the "Files" app and its "Download" folder of the iPad Pro.

Could it be that QQ Reader immediately removed it from the Download folder?  There should be a way to

1. Specify which app to open it (for example, other apps that should be able to open it include Panels and Chunky Reader)
2. Choose to just leave it in the Folder app and its Download folder, and let me decide when and how to use it later

I tried also Airdrop a PDF file and iPad let me choose from a series of apps to open it, including iBooks and all other apps that can handle PDF files, so a `.cbz` should be able to be treated the same way?

(the `.cbz` is a comicbook archive format, which may be a series of `.jpg` files. For example, on the MacBook, it can unzip that file into a folder of regular `.jpg` files (by the Unarchiver app))

Comment: An airdropped file might not even pass through the Downloads folder but end up directly in app selected as an target.